# Why is background image not working in html?

Tags: html, django, python-3.x

I want to make the links working but it is not responding. How to make it work? I have other links also which are working

**signup.html working link**

```
<img src="{% static 'users_assets/img/favicon.png' %}">
```

**signup.html not working link**

```
<div class="image-container set-full-height" style="background-image: url('static/users_assets/img/wizard-book.jpg')">
```

**Folder structure**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Change path `../../static/users_assets/img/wizard-book.jpg`

```
<div class="image-container set-full-height" style="background-image: url('../../static/users_assets/img/wizard-book.jpg')">
```

Answer (score -1):

div class="image-container set-full-height" style="background-image: url('myapp/project/static/users_assets/img/wizard-book.jpg')">

Comment: See if you can edit this to be inside a code block. :)